# .cph folders in a flutter project

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

.cph folders are being generated in every folder in a flutter project.
Even after deleting the folder after refreshing the folder is being recreated. [image]

Answer (score 3):

i also have the same thing.. i even had it in my c drive..

I think it's because of the "competitive programming helper" extension in vs code.. disabling it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same folders in

- visual studio code
- MacOS
- Angular project

I'm trying to find the root, but for the moment I didn't find anything.